# Talend : Generate and populate txt file and put in on FTP

Tags: talend, edi

I have a question in Talend :

I need to create a file with name like `"File_" + TalendDate.getDate("CCYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss") + ".txt"` and populate it with the result of a SQL query and add a "\t" separator on each column of each row.

After that, I need to connect to a FTP (Through tFTPConnection component), and put this file on a folder (Through tFTPPut component)

The main problem i encounter is that i don't know which composent i should use when i'll create the text file ? Should I use a tFileOutputPositional ? tFileOutputDelimited ? Another component ?

Moreover, i have another issue : When i'm connecting to the FTP, no worries but when i'm on the tFTPPut component, i have this issue :

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

[image]

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to execute your SQL query.

To generate the file you should use **tFileOutputDelimited** on the row data and change the field separator to tab "\t".

Set the filename directly in the **tFileOutputDelimited** component. Keep in mind that the path only contains forward slashes, e.g.:

```
"C:/my-folder/File_" + TalendDate.getDate("CCYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss") + ".txt"
```

Depending on your configuration it might help to set the ftp connection to passive mode (see more here https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-1643)